# How do popBackStack() and replace() operations differ?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've encountered some curious behavior in my application when managing Fragments and I was wondering if SO could help shed some light onto why this happens.

I have two Fragments, we'll call them Fragment A and Fragment B.  The general flow of my application is that when the user interacts with Fragment A in some way, Fragment B is shown by calling `fragmentTransaction.replace()` (this happens in all cases).  When I show Fragment B, I add Fragment A to the back stack; then, when the user presses the back button on Fragment B, Fragment A gets shown again by popping from the back stack.

That's all well and good, but today I discovered that there is a flow from Fragment B which calls `fragmentTransaction.replace()`, replacing Fragment B with the same instance of Fragment A that is currently on the back stack.

In and of itself there's nothing wrong with that, however the strange behavior arises when I go back from Fragment A into Fragment B.  If I called `fragmentTransaction.replace()`, the `onCreate()` method of Fragment B is not called.

However, if I popped Fragment A from the back stack and then replaced it with Fragment B, the `onCreate()` method of Fragment B is fired.  Why is this?

Note that all instances of Fragment A and Fragment B are created at the time their host Activity is launched.

Edit for clarification.  The case where `onCreate()` is called a second time is the following: Attach Fragment A => replace with Fragment B, adding Fragment A to the back stack => pop Fragment A using `popBackStack()` => replace Fragment A with Fragment B again.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`replace()` does 2 things:

1. Remove currently added fragment (A) from the container (C) you indicated
2. Add new fragment (B) to the same container

These 2 operations are what is saved as a Backstack record / transaction. Note that fragment A remains in `created` state, and its view is destroyed.

Now `popBackStack()` reverses your last transaction that you've added to BackStack.

In this case that would be 2 steps:

1. Remove B from C
2. Add A to C

After this, fragment B becomes `detached`, and if you did not keep references to it, it will be garbage collected.

To answer first part of your question, there's no `onCreate()` call, because FragmentB remained in `created` state. And answer to second part of the question is a bit longer.

First, it is important to understand that you don't actually add `Fragments` to Backstack, you add `FragmentTransactions`. So when you think that you "replace with Fragment B, adding Fragment A to the back stack", you actually add this whole operation to backstack - that is *replacement* of A with B. This replacement consists of 2 actions - remove A and add B.

Then, next step is popping of the transaction that contains this replacement. So you're not popping FragmentA, you're reversing "remove A, add B", which reversed is "remove B, add A".

And then final step should be clearer - there's no B that FragmentManager is aware of, so when you add it by replacing A with B at your last step, B needs to go through its early lifecycle methods - `onAttach()` and `onCreate()`.

Code below illustrates what is happening.

```java
FragmentManager fm  = getFragmentManager();
FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();

// 1. Show A
fm.beginTransaction()
  .add(fragmentA, R.id.container)
  .commit();

// 2. Replace A with B
// FragmentManager keeps reference to fragmentA;
// it stays attached and created; fragmentB goes 
// through lifecycle methods onAttach(), onCreate()
// and so on.
fm.beginTransaction()
  .replace(fragmentB, R.id.container)
  .addToBackstack(null)
  .commit();

// 2'. Alternative to replace() method
fm.beginTransaction()
  .remove(fragmentA)
  .add(fragmentB, R.id.container)
  .addToBackstack(null)
  .commit();

// 3. Reverse (2); Result - A is visible
// What happens:
//   1) fragmentB is removed from container, it is detached now;
//      FragmentManager doesn't keep reference to it anymore
//   2) Instance of FragmentA is placed back in the container
// Now your Backstack is empty, FragmentManager is aware only
// of FragmentA instance
fm.popBackStack();

// 4. Show B
// Since fragmentB was detached, it goes through its early
// lifecycle methods: onAttach() and onCreate().
fm.beginTransaction()
  .replace(fragmentB, R.id.container)
  .addToBackstack(null)
  .commit();
```

Comment: 1. I've edited my question to hopefully clarify further.  The strange thing about your solution is that it seems like in both cases Fragment B goes into a detached state and then gets restored.  `popBackStack()` must be doing something different; I'm just curious what that is.

Comment: Extended my answer, hopefully this clarifies things. Fragments and their transactions is rather hairy subject.

Comment: Okay, so if I manually replace Fragment B with Fragment A then another transaction record is added to the back stack.  That means that the FragmentManager still considers Fragment B to be in a detached state.  However, when I pop the only transaction that contains Fragment B then the FragmentManager considers that Fragment to no longer be attached because there are no transactions which include it.  Is that a proper understanding?  Also, thanks for the super informative help.

Comment: Glad to help! I'll try to answer sentence-by-sentence.

(1) I shown 2' only as an alternative, with effect same as 2 - just to clarify. (2) I'm not sure which step you're referring to, but if you added B, and did not fully remove it from FM, it will remain in attached and created state. Full removal would be when there's no transaction which is referring to it. (3) Basically yes, just FM _makes_ fragment not attached, that is changes its flags, calls onDetach() and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe because the fragment manager reuse the fragment instance rather recreate it. If the code inside Fragment B `onCreate()` requires to be executed when the fragment is shown, then move the code in another method like `onResume()`.