# Android: Difference between ft.remove() and popBackStack()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I am trying to remove a fragment from my stack. I am using this code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.my_id);
        if (currentFragment != null) {
            ft.remove(currentFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
```

Do I need to call popBackStack() with the above code?

```
fm.popBackStack();
```

Comment: I would take a look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793249/how-do-popbackstack-and-replace-operations-differ

Answer (score 6):

`remove()` will simply remove the fragment.

`popBackStack()` will remove current fragment and replace it with the last one from the stack. For this to work you need to do `addToBackstack()` on the last fragment transaction. But this is not what you want to do so don't do it.