# FragmentManager.popBackStack() adds fragment below the current one

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm learning how to use fragments properly. 
I have 4 fragments:

- A
- B
- Loading
- Complete

It should replace each other in this sequence:

**A** ==> **Loading** ==> **B** ==> **Loading** ==> **Complete**

Method that change my Fragment A into Loading:

```
    LoadingFragment loadingFragment = new LoadingFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean("fragmentA", true);

    loadingFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, loadingFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

Changing Fragment B into Loading looks similarly (only arguments are changed obviously)

Method that change Loading fragment into Fragment B:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentB())
                    .commit();

        }
    }).start();
```

Thread.sleep(...) is just a long operation...
Obviously I'm not adding `.addToBackStack(null)` this time.

Ok. Now the problem:

When I use `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` method, the previous fragment (A) is added below *(my fragment container is LinearLayout)* my actual fragment instead of replaceing it. According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17793959/3279023 it should work, but it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are experiencing looks OK to me. `popBackStack()` reverses the last **saved** operation, which in your case is: `replace A with Loading`.

So it replaces `Loading` with `A`, but that has no effect on `B` obviously, which you added without recording the transaction.

A solution could be using `addToBackStack()` in both cases, so that both transaction are registered, and then call `popBackStack()` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Several fragments can make one activity/screen. Backstack is like back arrow or go back to the last activity/screen.

Comment: I know this... but `addToBackStack()` method should remember all transaction and execute and inverse that